# Check Date is Greater Than C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a field in my Razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CreateContractStep1.StartDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="admin-form theme-primary">
            <label for="StartDate" class="field prepend-icon mbn">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreateContractStep1.StartDate, new { id = "StartDate", @class = "gui-input datepicker", placeholder = "From...", data_bind = "value: CreateContractStep1.StartDate" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CreateContractStep1.StartDate, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger fw400" })
                <label class="field-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
                </label>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently it has some validation present so that the field cannot be left blank. However I would like to add some validation. Based on another field called Termination Date which is in the Model.

I have tried this in my Model:

```
 [Display(Name = "From")]
 [Required]
 [GreaterThan("TerminationDate", true, "Termination date must be greater than or equal to Notification Date")]
 public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

But it's not really working as expected. It does not bring back the Validation Message. I am thinking that I may need a Custom Validator Attribute.

**Model:**

```
    #region Create Contract Step 1
    public class ContractStep1ViewModel
    {
        public ContractStep1ViewModel()
        {
            // Default named type to contract.
            NamedType = ContractNamedType.Contract;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Name *")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "The {0} has a maximum of {1} characters.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "The {0} has a maximum of {1} characters.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Contract Type *")]
        [Required]
        public ContractType? ContractType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Contract Or Sideletter *")]
        [Required]
        public ContractNamedType NamedType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Currency Used *")]
        [Required]
        public string Currency { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "From *")]
        [Required]
        [Compare("End Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "To")]
        [GreaterThan("StartDate", true, "End Date must be greater than or equal to Start Date")]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Signed")]
        public DateTime? SignedDate { get; set; }
    }

 public class TerminateContractViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid ContractId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid RowVersion { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime ContractStartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Notification Date")]
        [Required]
        [GreaterThan("ContractStartDate", false, "Notification date must be greater than or equal to Contract Start Date")]
        public DateTime NotificationDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Termination Date")]
        [Required]
        [GreaterThan("NotificationDate", true, "Termination date must be greater than or equal to Notification Date")]
        public DateTime TerminationDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Post Term Collection End Date")]
        [Required]
        [GreaterThan("TerminationDate", true, "Post term collection date must be greater than or equal to Termination Date")]
        public DateTime PostTermCollectionEndDate { get; set; }

        // search
        public ContractSearchViewModel SearchModel { get; set; }
        // pagination
        public PagingModel PagingInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming `GreaterThan` is a custom attribute? If so, you do need to add the relevant rules on the client side, as well. This is a good example: https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/asp-net-mvc-lessthan-and-greaterthan-validation-attributes/

Comment: It is a custom attribute. But is there another method I could use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "another method" - could you elaborate?

Comment: The MVC Folproof Validation library has a GreaterThanAttribute and hooks for unobtrusive validation already: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=foolproof

Comment: I will give that a try. I was just wondering if I could do something in the controller, but I guess as the model is already handelling the validation, best just to use the model.

Comment: Done correctly, the validation logic in an attribute will be applied during model-binding. You _could_ just do a manual check in the action method in your controller which handles the form submission, and manually add an error to ModelState. That's entirely up to what makes the most sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding

```
[Display(Name = "Termination Date")]
public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; set; }
```

Into the Model and then adding in a Form Field for the `Termination Date`. I then chose to hide the field as it was not required to be shown. I then checked that the validation worked with a couple of scenarios.

```
    <div class="form-group hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CreateContractStep1.TerminationDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="admin-form theme-primary">
    <label for="SignedDate" class="field prepend-icon mbn">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreateContractStep1.TerminationDate, new { id = "TerminationDate", @class = "gui-input datepicker", placeholder = "Termination Date (Optional)...", data_bind = "value: CreateContractStep1.TerminationDate" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CreateContractStep1.TerminationDate, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
<label class="field-icon">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
</label>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```